# Matlab:How to define a dynamic cell array in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I need to store some vectors,but i don't kown how many vectors.I want to ask is there exits cell array with undefined size that means denamic cell arrays in Matlab?Or can i only predefine a very large cell array to meet my demand?

Answer (score 2):

All arrays in matlab are 'dynamic' (i.e. resizeable)

```
>> a = [1,2,3]
a =
     1     2     3

>> a(7) = 7
a =
     1     2     3     0     0     0     7
```

Same with cell arrays:

```
>> b = {1,2,3}; b{7} = 7
b = 
    [1]    [2]    [3]    []    []    []    [7]
```